# Layout category not showing in jframe palette in eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5IQw.png)
Layouts category not present in palette

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6pl3.png)
Layouts category not present in options

I cannot find the layouts category in jframe palette in eclipse neon. I tried looking for it in palette manager if it was not selected but didn't find it there either. I searched for jar file for it on internet but didn't find anything. Please help!

Comment: Note that Eclipse Neon is now 4 years and 8 releases old, you might want use a newer Eclipse (2019-12 is the current release).

Comment: You see, I am in an internship and I don't have admin rights, so I can't install newer eclipse on my system and I have to make use with this version only. Do you know how I can get my layout category back?